# subviews are overlapping inside the scrollview

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

My original question is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16158170/scrollview-is-showing-only-the-last-added-subview?noredirect=1#comment23867389_16158170), but I wanted to open new question to explain in better in briefly way about my issue.
I try to draw 3 subviews on a scrollview and make that scroll horizontally. The content size is Ok, I can scroll up to three times (width of 3 subviews) but the problem is that all of the subviews are drawn over each other so obviously I can see only the last subview.

The subview is loaded from a `xib` file. Here is the relevant code:

```
startX = 0;//static int startX ;
for (App_Table *_appTable in sorted) {

    NSArray *arr = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AppTableView" owner:self options:nil];
    
    AppTableView *aView = [arr objectAtIndex:0];
    aView.frame = CGRectMake(startX, 0, aView.bounds.size.width, aView.bounds.size.height);
    aView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:aView];
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.contentSize.width+aView.frame.size.width
                                             ,self.scrollView.contentSize.height);
    startX = startX + aView.frame.size.width;

   AppTableView *_appTableView = (AppTableView *) [[self.scrollView subviews] lastObject];

    _appTableView.txtADDRESS.text = _appTable.address;//Fill in the form, no need to write all the form fields code because it's the same way.
}
```

As you can see, the `X` origin is incremented by the width of the view, I debugged to confirm, however the subviews are overlapping one above the other, and finally just one subview (the last one) is visible. I checked that by setting the background to red color, and only one red background subview is loaded.
If you can help with and want to post your answer in the original question  for which I make a bounty, feel free.

Thanx.

Comment: You're incrementing `startX` by the width of the view. Try logging the width there and make sure it's not zero.

Comment: Does the red rectangle show at the beginning or at the end of the scroll view?

Comment: @marzapower at the beginning of the scroll view

Comment: @PartiallyFinite The width is not 0, I checked it already :)

Comment: Try changing the scrollview `contentSize` *before* adding `aView` as a subview. The scrollview might be pushing everything back if it exceeds the bounds. Not always, but sometimes does that.

Comment: Thanx for the note, I tried it but it doesn't fix the issue there, I also checked the frames with print object debugger command to make sure it's not null and is really drawing on the scrollview.

Comment: It's worth to note when I stop my app and run the following command in the debugger `po [[UIApp keyWindow] recursiveDescription]` I got the frames of the subviews exactly the same, meaning the X is always at `0` which explain why they are overlapping, but when I debug that on instantly in runtime, the X is incrementing and the frames are different, so everything appears fine.

Comment: Where in your code do you have this? Have you logged startX to see how it increments each time through the loop?